# Fetching message with aws-sdk-go / roleARN / queueARN (sqs)

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, roles, amazon-sqs, amazon-iam

I have a sqs queue created (which has the queueARN). I also have an IAM role created(which provides the roleARN and has access permissions to the queueARN). I'm trying to fetch messages from the queue using this role, but I'm unable to find a sample go code to do this operation.

Any hints?

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a good starting point.

https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/blob/master/service/sqs/examples_test.go

Comment: Unfortunately - that link doesn't consist of roleARN or queue ARN.